# Copy user template issue powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I want to use a user instance/user template to create my new users, so I wrote this:

```
$userInstance = "'" + "Get-ADUser -Filter { CN -eq " + "'" + $_.userInstance + "'" + " } -Properties *" + "'";
$path = $_.Path;
 #create user
New-ADUser -SAMAccountName $_.SAMAccountName -Instance $userInstance -Name $_.name -DisplayName $_.displayName -Path "OU=$Path" -GivenName $_.givenname -Surname $_.surname -userPrincipalName $_.userprincipalname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $_.Password -AsPlainText -Force) -PassThru | Enable-ADAccount;
```

But it doesn't copy the member of properties, or the home folder path.
I must be overlooking something because I checked the Microsoft forms and other users seemed to be doing this same trick.

I read about the -expand param but I want to copy all of the properties so that shouldn't be what I want to use. Hence I use -Properties *.

When I searched this forum I couldn't find any answers for this exact problem. If anyone finds an answer please let me know! Maybe I didn't search using the right words :). Thanks for any replies in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly then group memberships are not duplicated if you use the `-instance` parameter of `New-ADUser`. You will probably have to do it yourself.

Something like this should work for that:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -id "NewUserName" -MemberOf (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -id "Templateuser")
```

Homedirectory *should* work though.

Comment: Hi Paul, that seems to be true. I added that just after a short sleep (the script didn't seem to find the user right after it was created) and it works now. When I save the homefolder in the template with variable %username% it automatically makes it the actual username in the attributes. Maybe I'll need a seperate command for that as well. Thanks so far!

Comment: @MellevanAar That´s true, sadly it doesnt see the variable. What you can do though is put your template instance in a variable and then just edit the property on the object (`$templateUser.HomeDirectory = ...`). This will not change the template user in AD but the `New-ADUser -Instance $templateUser ...` cmdlet will use the changed property value

Comment: Hmm, that does seem like a bit more of a hassle than just using                 `Set-ADuser -Identity "$SAMAccountName" -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory "\\share\bla";` after the sleep. But I can't seem to make that work ;) (The share is the same across our templates, I checked.)

Comment: @MellevanAar $true :)